# Interleaving two binary files by fixed-size blocks

Tags: perl, coreutils

We have `paste(1)` which can interleave files by lines.  Out of
curiosity, I wonder if there's some binary equivalent.  It should copy
the first N bytes from file A to stdout, then the first N bytes of file
B, then the second N bytes of file A, etc.

The solution I came up with:

```
$/ = \512;
my @files = map { open( my $fh, "<", $_ ); $fh } @ARGV;
while (@files) {
    @files = grep { my $c = <$_>; defined $c and print $c } @files;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like shell to me.

Comment: Edited tags to specify perl to match your solution.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I tried to find a solution in shell. But I could only come up with one in perl. This question is mostly me being curious, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: What *matters* is that you tag you tag your question with shell and post code in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do:

```
paste -d '\0' <(xxd -p -c512 file1) <(xxd -p -c512 file2) | xxd -p -r > merged
```

With `zsh`:

```bsh
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system

size=${1?}; shift

fds=()
for file do
  sysopen -u fd -- "$file" || exit
  fds+=$fd
done

until
  eof=true
  for fd in $fds; do
    sysread -s "$size" -i$fd -o1 && eof=false
  done
  $eof
do
  continue
done
```

Comment: It looks like I don't need `-d '\0'`.

Comment: @7efkvNEq, it may very well be, but here there's no point adding that TAB in between the two records for xxd to ignore it later, so adding that `-d '\0'` means less work for both `paste` and `xxd` (and the kernel to shovel those TABs through the pipe).